# Bootstrap Image Resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Ok, So I am creating a website with Bootstrap and I have run into an issue.  I have placed an image in the nav bar in the logo and then I go to resize the browser to force mobile layout. When I get to where the image should start re-sizing, it drops below (or above) the menu toggle before re-sizing.

I have even tried adding `.img-responsive` to it but that is no help.

Here is an image of what I am talking about: [image]

And here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/40/" class="img-responsive" alt="LOGO"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this. You can use media queries to set `max-width` or percentage `width` to `.navbar-brand`.

The clearest solution might be to use CSS3 `calc` to make it take 100% width minus the space that the menu button is taking (22px width + 20px of padding + 2px of border + 15px of margin = 59px total space). And because your image is pushed down at 390px screen width, your media query should be:

```
@media (max-width: 390px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        width: calc(100% - 59px);
    }
}
```

Check the [JSFiddle with the result](http://jsfiddle.net/M22pa/).

My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24088296/1924026) might help you as well.